How can the current be sustained in a tethered satellite system?
I have a question about how the current is sustained in a tethered satellite system TSS-1R.
In the most simplified model, the system is basically a straight wire (connecting the shuttle and satellite) moving across a magnetic field (the ionosphere).

A charge $+q$ in the wire experiences an upward magnetic force $qvB$, and there should be a current flowing upward. However, as this is not a circuit loop, positive charges should soon accumulate at the upper end and stop the current.
Of course, the current actually sustained. But how is this possible?
My guess is that negative ions in the ionosphere are attracted to the satellite, so there is no significant building up of charges. Is this true?

I believe that that was what was supposed to happen. In practice it seems the cable was unstable, but I am not sure if that was due to the corona discharge, current or whatever.
I was not aware that they were trying this scheme again.
What is more interesting is "why do this?"  There is no free lunch and  power is gained at the expense of slowing down the space-craft. A rocket engine has to be run to keep the speed up.  The magic is that you get more energy this way. Pushing a spacecraft at orbital speed gives a lot of ${\bf Power}={\bf F}_{\rm push}\cdot {\bf v}$  --- much more   than you would get by simply using the fuel in a fuel cell to generate electricity. The extra energy comes from partially recovering the large amount of kinetic energy that, in addition to its chemical energy,   the fuel was given to get it to orbital speed.
